# Laravel - add in core/routes/ if username exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
Route::middleware('admin')->group(function () {
        Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
        Route::get('profile', 'AdminController@profile')->name('profile');
        Route::post('profile', 'AdminController@profileUpdate')->name('profile.update');
        Route::get('password', 'AdminController@password')->name('password');
        Route::post('password', 'AdminController@passwordUpdate')->name('password.update');
```

I have this code in routes and I want to add "if username == "staff"

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
```

not others pages.

Comment: make a middleware that verifies the username and use it on that route. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#defining-middleware

Answer (score 0):

First create StaffMiddleware.php in following path app/Http/Middleware/StaffMiddleware.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class StaffMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request. User must be logged in to do admin check
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::user()->username == 'staff')
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->guest('/');
    }
}
```

In app/Http/Kernel.php add the following line

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        // your existing code
        'staff' => \App\Http\Middleware\StaffMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

Rewrite the following route

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
```

TO

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('dashboard')->middleware('staff');
```

Now whenever you want to check this condition you just need to add `->middleware('staff')` in route.